# Why I am getting error when setting innerHTML of an element to some localstorage value through get Item in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, conditional-statements

Actually I am trying to set a

elements innerHTML to some value from local storage ,It shows the value for the first time but whenever I trying to reload the page it shows error like the screenshot below!

[Error showing after reload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xlb90.png)

here is the code-

```
const getName = window.localStorage.getItem("name");

   if(getName.charAt(0) == "M"){
  document.getElementById("myidname").innerHTML = "some message";

   }else{
console.log("error")
   }

<p id='myidname'></p>
```

I tried to wrap statements into a method then using that method inside the

element but still showing same error.

Comment: error says that element with an id of `myidname` does not exist. Place the code inside `useEffect` and also try logging if element is not `null`

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this issue, you should check if getName is not null or undefined before trying to access its properties. You can follow code:

```
const getName = window.localStorage.getItem("name");
if (getName && getName.charAt(0) == "M") {
    document.getElementById("myidname").innerHTML = "some message";
} else {
    console.log("error");
}
```

By following these few steps, you ensure that you handle cases where the local storage value may not exist or may not have the expected format.